# Can't put object into hashmap connected to other object

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm making this console based game.

But I can't understand this bit or why it is wrong to do it like this.

So basically I have 10 rooms
so a room has the following things:

-A roomnumber

-A hashmap that contains a Room as value and a String as key

Now the problem, A room can be exited from 4 direction North, East, South, West so that's the String/key in the hashmap.
It can also have 2 exits or 1 or 3.
So in that hashmap I save the direction as key and as value another room object so I can keep track which exit goes to which room.

so I have a method for adding exits. that looks like this:

```
public class Room {
    private int RoomNo;
    private HashMap<String, Room> Exits;

    public Room(int roomNo){
        Exits = new HashMap<String, Room>();
        this.RoomNo = roomNo;

    }

    public void Addexits(Room room, String exitDirection){
            Exits.put(exitDirection,room);
    }
```

And than in the game class I create 10 rooms and use call the addexits method to add exits that looks like this:

```
Rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
     //initialize all rooms
     room1 = new Room(1);
     room1.Addexits(room4,"West");
     room1.Addexits(room3,"East");
     room2 = new Room(2);
     room2.Addexits(room2,"North");
     room2.Addexits(room2,"South");
     room3 = new Room(3);
     room3.Addexits(room3,"West");
     room3.Addexits(room3,"East");
     room4 = new Room(4);
     room4.Addexits(room4,"West");
     room4.Addexits(room4,"East");
```

However as you can see with room1 I try to add 2 exits 1 in the west to room4 and 1 in the east to room3 however when I run this it shows this in the hashmap:
West -> null
East -> null

But when I add 2 exits both with object room1 it puts it like it should be like this:

West -> room1
East -> room1

So I don't really get what I'm doing wrong each room has its own hashmap on creation and the rooms are already created so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: when you did `room1.addExit(room4, "west")` and after that you re-initiazied `room4 `by `room4 = new Room(4)` This lost its reference in the room1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize all rooms first and then add exits;

```
 room1 = new Room(1);
 room2 = new Room(2);
 room3 = new Room(3);
 room4 = new Room(4);
 room1.Addexits(room4,"West");
 room1.Addexits(room3,"East");
 room2.Addexits(room2,"North");
 room2.Addexits(room2,"South");
 room3.Addexits(room3,"West");
 room3.Addexits(room3,"East");
 room4.Addexits(room4,"West");
 room4.Addexits(room4,"East");
```

Comment: Yeah i need to wait 4 more min

Answer (score 0):

In the below code

```
Rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
 //initialize all rooms
 room1 = new Room(1);
 room1.Addexits(room4,"West");
 room1.Addexits(room3,"East");
```

You are adding room3 and room4 which are not initialized still. you have just declared it. Thats why you are getting null. Try adding it after you have initialized.

```
Rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
 //initialize all rooms
 room1 = new Room(1);
 room2 = new Room(2);
 room2.Addexits(room2,"North");
 room2.Addexits(room2,"South");
 room3 = new Room(3);
 room3.Addexits(room3,"West");
 room3.Addexits(room3,"East");
 room4 = new Room(4);
 room4.Addexits(room4,"West");
 room4.Addexits(room4,"East");
 //here you add room4 and room3 exits
 room1.Addexits(room4,"West");
 room1.Addexits(room3,"East");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you call Addexits() it is not guaranteed, that the room you're adding already exists. So switching your statements around should fix this.

```
Rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
//initialize all rooms
room1 = new Room(1);
room2 = new Room(2);
room3 = new Room(3);
room4 = new Room(4);

// add all exits
room1.Addexits(room4,"West");
room1.Addexits(room3,"East");

room2.Addexits(room2,"North");
room2.Addexits(room2,"South");

room3.Addexits(room3,"West");
room3.Addexits(room3,"East");

room4.Addexits(room4,"West");
room4.Addexits(room4,"East");
```

Also note that you are adding room3 as exit to room3, same for rooms 2 and 4. I don't know if that's the intention.